# Are Named Placeholders, .format(**DictObject,...), an Example of Using **kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I found this code in a sample program:

```
>>> monitor = {'top': 5, 'left': 0, 'width': 1000, 'height': 200}
>>> output = 'sct-{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png'.format(**monitor)
>>> print(output)
sct-5x0_1000x200.png
```

It looks like `.format(**monitor)` is a `**kwargs` 'kind of thing', but I haven't used these things before.

I 'lifted' this code and know how it works, but can my understanding here land me in a kwargmire?

I was about to post this question but ran this first:

```
>>> '{} {} buckle my {top}'.format(1, 2, **monitor)
'1 2 buckle my 5'
```

and so I guess I can now say I've actively worked with `kwargs`.